# ng-model not updating my object values

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I have a one-page application using angularJS.
I have in my controller a user object defined like this :

```
this.user = {
    'name':'Robert',
    'age':'30'
}
```

I made a form to update those informations prefilled with those user's informations on my page such like this :

```
<form name="userForm" ng-submit="userForm.$valid && pageCtrl.userForm(user)" novalidate>
    <label for="name">Name *</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" ng-model='pageCtrl.user.name' class="form-control" required/>

    <label for="age">Age *</label>
    <input type="text" name="age" ng-model='pageCtrl.user.age' class="form-control" required/>

    <span ng-if='!userForm.$valid' class="error">Invalid form</span>
    <input type="submit" value="Save my informations" class="btn btn-success"/>
</form>
```

My problem is the following : in the header bar of the page the username is displayed ({{pageCtrl.user.name}}). 
When the user acts on the form by changing his name, this is updating before the form is saved.
I'd like to wait for the form submission to see the username updated. But i still want to get my form prefilled with user's informations.

Do you have any idea about how to do this?

Thank you by advance

Comment: Just change pageCtrl.user.name to something like pageCtrl.user.saved_name and update pageCtrl.user.saved_name after the submit was a success.

Comment: in the header bar use something like pageCtrl.updatedUser.name and set inside controller and after form submit pageCtrl.updatedUser = pageCtrl.user

Comment: You can achieve by this using **ng-if** also. Use Boolean value to check form is submitted or not and then show username in the header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a copied object to only apply the changes when the user save the form :

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('pageCtrl', function() {
  var vm = this;  
  vm.user = {
    'name':'Robert',
    'age':'30'
  };
  
  vm.tmpUser = {};

  vm.update = function() {
    vm.user = angular.copy(vm.tmpUser);
  };

  vm.reset = function() {
    vm.tmpUser = angular.copy(vm.user);
  };
  
  vm.reset();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="pageCtrl as pageCtrl">
  <form name="userForm" ng-submit="userForm.$valid" novalidate>
    <label for="name">Name *</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" ng-model='pageCtrl.tmpUser.name' class="form-control" required/>

    <label for="age">Age *</label>
    <input type="text" name="age" ng-model='pageCtrl.tmpUser.age' class="form-control" required/>

    <span ng-if='!userForm.$valid' class="error">Invalid form</span>
    <input type="submit" ng-click="pageCtrl.update()" ng-disabled="!userForm.$valid" value="Save my informations" class="btn btn-success" />
  </form>  
  <pre>user = {{pageCtrl.user | json}}</pre>
  <pre>tmpUser = {{pageCtrl.tmpUser | json}}</pre>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use your **ng-model** to bind to a temp object , like :

```
this.tmpUser = {
      'name':'Robert',
      'age':'30'
   }
```

**Your form would be:**

```
<form name="userForm" ng-submit="userForm.$valid && pageCtrl.userForm(user)" novalidate>
    <label for="name">Name *</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" ng-model='pageCtrl.tmpUser.name' class="form-control" required/>

    <label for="age">Age *</label>
    <input type="text" name="age" ng-model='pageCtrl.tmpUser.age' class="form-control" required/>

    <span ng-if='!userForm.$valid' class="error">Invalid form</span>
    <input type="submit" value="Save my informations" class="btn btn-success"/>
</form>
```

**keep your user object :**

```
this.user = {
    'name':'Robert',
    'age':'30'
}
```

**And when you submit the form, update the user object.**

Answer (score 0):

Let's say this is your header,

```
<header><span ng-show="pageCtrl.formSubmitted">{{ pageCtrl.user.name }}</span></header>
```

In the pageCtrl.userForm(user) function just make the pageCtrl.formSubmitted true once your form is successfully submitted.  Cool things, is you can use this boolean for other purposes as well.